# Update an old activity in Runkeeper and have that update in MyFitnessPal?

Tags: runkeeper

Setup is Runkeeper for Activity logging, automatically synced to MyFitnessPal for calorie counting.

If I change the activity type in a Runkeeper activity that is a few days old, is it possible to resync the activity with MyFitnessPal to update the calories burned?